# Customize Cypress terminal summary

Tags: cypress

Is there a way how to customize the Cypress summary in the terminal?

[image]

I have screenshot tests and I would like to divide failing tests. So I would like to add an extra column, something like Failing Screenshots. Because for me is a big difference between failing code and failing screenshot match. I tried several times to google something, but nothing.

Comment: Isn't it what you are looking for? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-terminal-report

Comment: I tried this one, but I did not find any summary customization.

Comment: Do you have an example of a failing screenshot match (the test and/or log from GUI)? I wonder if the results have this type of fail. If so, there may be a way to add it to the summary.

Comment: You can use this example https://github.com/jaredpalmer/cypress-image-snapshot/tree/master/examples. It is for an older Cypress, but it should be easy to update the version. For me works only the command `npm run cypress:run`.

Comment: Better try with different reporting methods. Cypress many plugins for reporting,